# Convert all columns of a dataframe of a certain type to another type

Tags: pandas, select, type-conversion

Suppose I have a dataframe where some columns are of type `object`, and others are not. How do I convert inplace the type of the `object` columns to `float`, while leaving the others unchanged? I tried

```
cols_to_convert = (df.dtypes == 'object')
df[cols_to_convert] = df[cols_to_convert].astype(float)
```

but I get

```
IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).
```

Comment: `df.loc[:, cols_to_convert]`.

Comment: @QuangHoang it works! Can you explain me what I did wrong? Or what you are doing right :-)

Comment: `df[series]` slices along index, `df.loc[:, series]` slices along columns. More genarally `df.loc[indexes, columns]`. You can do, in your case `cols_to_convert = df.columns[df.dtypes=='object']` to get the list of columns, then `df[list_of_columns` slices along the columns (names).